# Logging using spring boot sl4j

Tags: spring-boot

In my application properties i have written the below for logging

```
 logging.level.com.intro.dmp=INFO
 logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
 logging.level.com.intro.dmp=ERROR
 logging.file=application.log
```

and my Application is below , but it is not creating any log file rather displaying in the console . What is that i am missing here , it is reading application properties

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.intro")
@PropertySource("file:src/main/resources/application.properties")
 public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    logger.debug("--Application Started--");
    logger.error("Check the main Articles");
    logger.info("Checking files ");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes will resolve your issue:

1. In *application.properties* file, you need to provide quotes to the file name. i.e.:`logging.file='application.log'`
2. You can remove `@PropertySource` annotation. Spring Boot will, by default, look for *application.properties* file at `src/main/resources/`.

Comment: Not Working my side

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal okay. Then just try the first point. Keep `@PropertySource` as it is in your code.

Comment: Not working , do i need to include logback.xml , i am using the latest version  of spring boot ?